# How to get first name & last name in android?

Tags: android, gmail, android-contacts, user-accounts

How to get user first name, last name, email id from email accounts or whatsapp accounts or any accounts?

I have tried this code

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
     Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
```

but in this code only gets account type & account name.

I want first name & last account with email id.

Plz help me. How can?

Thanks & Regards,

Nitin

Comment: I think this will helpo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951609/retrieval-of-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts-results-in-1-and-nu